# Relation kernels of linear operators

Tags: vector-spaces, operator-theory

$V$ is a vector space. $T$ and $U$ are two linear operators on $V$. For finite dimensional, $\dim\ker(TU)=\dim\ker(T)+\dim\ker(U)$.
But, what about for infinite case?

Comment: $\dim \ker TU = \dim \ker T + \dim \ker U$ is wrong. Consider the case where $T$ is a projection, so $T^2 = T$, or the case where $T = U = 0$ and the right hand side is bigger than $\dim V$. I think you want $\le$.

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/linmultialg/diffeqdim.pdf   In page 4, what does it mean?

Comment: "Assume $U$ is onto". In the finite-dimensional case that means that $U$ is an automorphism, which means that the theorem is pretty much trivial.

Comment: Okay,thank you. In same case, what about infinite dimensional?